# Cross origin requests fails while using HTTP

Tags: angularjs, jboss, cors, cross-domain, wildfly

In my AngularJs Application, I get a cross-origin-error when Angular enters a rest interface (using chrome and IE11)

What you see in the chrome console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:9080/user/api/whoami. 
 Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: 
 http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

On serverside, the rest interface is implemented with camel:

```
restConfiguration()
    .enableCORS(true)
    .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers")
    .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    .component("servlet")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
    .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");
```

This question isalready asked here but always deals with files loaded locally.

As local applicationserver Jboss is used (9080)
For the frontend Angular is used (8080)
I even do not understand why a cross-origin-request is existent

Comment: Did you try to use CORS Chrome Extension ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: @Zooli thx, after installing the Extension I still have the same issue, so it should be on the frontend-side.

Comment: Additional: This issue is only present when interface is set to localhost. It works fine on the devServer

Answer (score 3):

The Appication is not able to connect to an adress named **localhost**, thus the error message says

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, ...

Changing the interface to **http://localhost**... and it's all fine